# Database design for recipe app with shopping list feature (iOS CoreData)

Tags: ios, database, core-data, relational-database, database-deadlocks

I'm working on a recipe app that will have a shopping list feature and I'd like to know if approach is not wrong.

```
Recipe (one to many)
- title
- serving
- image meta
- ingredients
- steps
- note

Recipe Category (has many Recipe)
- main
- side
- ...

Shopping List (has many recipe ingredients)
- recipe[3].ingredients[2]
- recipe[5].ingredients[3]
- recipe[5].ingredients[4]
- ...
```

So basically Shopping List entities will have reference of ingredients from Recipe entity. I understand that it's best to make Ingredient as a separate entity but since users may enter ingredients in an inconsistent way with / without amount, I chose to make it an attribute to Recipe entity.

I believe Core Data is some kind of ORM, like Doctrine in PHP and I've seen a number of use cases where each entity doesn't necessarily have an id attribute. In a traditional relational database, the relationship is built upon id attribute of mutual entities but Core Data seems to be able to establish a relationship without the need of id.

So my approach with Shopping List entity is that, I will make a reference of ingredient like Recipe[3].ingredients[4] and I wonder if this is an acceptable practice or even just plain wrong way of thinking.

Since Shopping List entity will be a pure reference of other entities, I don't even know if I need to have an entity for that. If iPhone has some kind of local storage, can I just use that instead? It's different question but I just want to know the right approach for persisting Shopping List records.

**UPDATE**

Shopping List entity should also store custom items that user will add via custom field. I wonder if the following diagram establishes this relationship correctly.

[image]

Comment: Your shopping list consists of recipes, and one value from their ingredients array, right? If you don't have to add all the ingredients in one go (e.g. if the user already has some ingredients) I would do it the same way you are doing it. Purchased Items [{ id:x, timestamp:y, owner:recipeX, ingredient:p }]

Comment: My shopping list will consist of ingredients of recipes, not necessarily recipes and random items that user may add (custom field). Please see my update with diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up your ingredients as independent objects like this:

```
ID_1 = {title:"Tomato", x:y, p:k etc}
ID_2 = {title:"Bread"}
ID_3 = {title:"Cheese"}
ID_4 = {title:"Sugar"}
```

Set up your recipes objects like this:

```
ID_A = {ingredients:[ID_1, ID_2, ID_3], title:"Margherita", serving:2 }
ID_B = {ingredients:[ID_2, ID_3], title:"Cheese on Toast", serving:1 }
ID_C = {ingredients:[ID_4], title:"Caramel", serving:6 }
```

Set up your shopping lists like this:

```
ID_k = {purchase:[ID_1,ID_2,ID_3,ID_4] timestamp:[NSDate date]}
```

For custom ingredients (entered by the user) add to your ingredients database dynamically and reference in the same way, e.g.

```
ID_5 = {title:"Custom Ingredient"}
```

You've captured the relationship between recipes and their ingredients (and any characteristics those ingredients might have, such as nutritional value) as well as the relationship between shopping lists and ingredients.

If you need to tie the relationship between shopping list and recipe, or if you only want to buy some ingredients in a recipe, you could do something like this:

```
ID_k = [{recipe:ID_A, ingredients:[ID_1,ID_2] timestamp:[NSDate date]},{}]
```

**UPDATE**

When the user starts to enter an ingredient, e.g. "To", do a string search of your ingredients database and make suggestions, such as "Tomato". Where no existing entries can be found, allow the user to add their own. This will reduce the number of redundant entries.

For quantity, add an additional variable to the ingredients objects, e.g.

```
ID_1 = {title:"Tomato Puree", measurement:"liter"}
ID_2 = {title:"Bread", measurement:"gram"}
ID_3 = {title:"Cheese", measurement:"gram"}
```

in the recipes section:

```
ID_A = {ingredients:[ID_1, ID_2, ID_3], quantity:[0.5, 200, 300], title:"Margherita", serving:2 }
```

and in the shopping list objects:

```
ID_k [{recipe:ID_A, ingredients:[ID_1,ID_2], quantity:[2,300,200], timestamp:[NSDate date]}, {}]
```

When displaying the data to the user, you can check the measurement type of the ingredient first and replace the float value with a more human-readable string.

For instance, if you're quantity is "0.5" and your measurement is "literal" (or something like that), you can display "half", or 0.25 is "quarter" etc. For other measurement types, e.g. "gram", just display the quantity and the measurement directly, e.g. 300 grams.

Comment: Thank you. The only issue I have with having Ingredient as an independent object is that, user is highly likely to make inconsistent random entries with/without unit quantity like, `3 tomatos, 1/2 tbsp sugar, potato, handful of cherries` and the like. This way, it's difficult to capture unique record of ingredients and end up with many redundant records with varying quantity. I can set some constraints on user entry by proving a quantity field along with an ingredient name but it may be overwhelming on a mobile device to fill out many small fields hence I made it an attribute of Recipe.

Comment: I should add to the updated answer above, where no quantity is specified, rely on a default value. But in any case, you're probably going to have to define the relationship between e.g. a 'handful'  and some metric value somewhere. If you take a look at the MyFitnessPal app, you can see they struggle with this exact issue, different measurement types of the same (or slightly different) types of ingredients.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Although I've decided not to make the ingredient as an independent object, your insight made me re-think through the problem. The essential part of my app is to make the user input process really fast without requiring fine details like quantity, unit. It's targeted toward users like myself who likes simple stuff. I've developed a special UI that makes this input process easy with a free text ingredient field and I think I should keep that. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, best of luck! I agree with what you're saying re keeping it simple, there's a lot of cluttered UI out there as it is.